# Is there any universal algorithm converting grammar to Turing Machine?

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, computability, formal-languages, automata

Is there any algorithm converting grammar into Turing Machine? It seems that there has to be one( but equivalence of Turing Machine and c.e. language is not proved algorithmatically in both direction, $G\Rightarrow TM$ is just a proof about a simulation to generating words of the language), If there is, how about it's computational complexity?

Comment: If you have an algorithm that gives you a TM which simulates the grammar's derivations, that is basically the conversions. To get an accepting TM simply compare the derived word to your input word; if they are equal accept, otherwise not.

Comment: @PeterLeupold If I do not know any thing about the Turing Machine that simulates the Grammar, what do I have to do?

Comment: You put S on the TM tape. Then you just search some left-hand side of a rule and apply the corresponding rule there. If you arrive at a terminal word or do not find any application sites you stop. This is the straight-forward way to simulate the grammar, see e.g. http://www.cs.tut.fi/~elomaa/teach/iTCS-12-5.pdf page 5. Generating the TM instructions will be some work, but not too much. Probably linear in the size of the input grammar. But I do not have a reference for that.

Comment: @PeterLeupold cs.tut.fi/~elomaa/teach/iTCS-12-5.pdf assumes that we have the language and the grammar, but we have only grammar. you may check the assumptions and the configure of the TM. anyway, thank you for your comments.

Comment: For the proof that is sketched you only need the grammar. Nothing else. What do you even mean by "have the language"? It is an infinite thing, you cannot "have" it for a construction. You can only have finite representations like the grammar.

Comment: @PeterLeupold I mean what the author means. It is infinite, but for every given word, the Turing Machine can accept it or generate according to the grammar, so in fact, he supposes the Turing Machine have the language,such an approach can be used for proof of equivalence, but I do not think it can be modified to or convert to Turing Machine not having the language.

Comment: Reversion of the procedure converting Turing Machine to Grammar is an approach, and is likely easy, I will try.

Comment: The pdf discussed is no longer available via that link. Any of you knows where I can find it currently? Thanks